# skip docs in cloudant search query

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I am trying to achieve pagination using cloudant search query

> https://username.cloudant.com/dbname/_design/searchall/_search/test?q=myquery&include_docs=true&stale=ok&limit=10&skip=5

but skip option is ignored! , if skip is not available then how can i achieve pagination ?

**Edit :**

I found it ,its supported via bookmarks https://cloudant.com/for-developers/search/

Comment: How can I get the 3rd or 4th page if I am on the 1st page with the bookmarks option ?